# ios app crashes on re-open

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, crash, instruments

I've gone through and made sure the memory usage is good on my app and everything seems to check out. Most of the time when you switch apps and switch back, the app opens just fine. However, if you use the app a lot and then let the phone idle until it turns off and then turn it back on - the app will crash out after unlocking the device. How can I dissect what the reason is? Is there some kind of crash log kept on the device by chance?

*note I can't use xcode instruments for this particular situation because the phone will never idle it's self to sleep when connected to the cable and I can't get a crash by manually sleeping the device. I don't think idling to sleep is the issue, it's just something I have noticed before a crash happens.

Comment: can you add crash logs also, that will help. Also as you say you have checked for proper memory management - hope you have checked with both Instruments and Static memory analyser.

Comment: When you crash and then connect back to Xcode, there should be information under the devices tab in the device logs section.  ...also possibly console messages in the console section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get to your device's crash log upon syncing.

OS X:
~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/MobileDevice//

Windows XP:
C:\Documents and Settings\Application Data\Apple computer\Logs\CrashReporter\\

Windows Vista:
C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Apple computer\Logs\CrashReporter\MobileDevice\\